# Composer dependency constraint

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there a possibility to let composer install a package only when the PHP version is below a given version.

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

`"ircmaxell/password-compat": "dev-master"`

I have found this package to be useful because I have a webserver which runs on PHP 5.4 and I need the password_* functions which are only available >= PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can find the details on the [packagist website](https://packagist.org/), but basically, the package/dependency should be defined with this requirement:

```
{
    "name": "ircmaxell/password-compat",
    "description": "A compatibility library for the proposed simplified password hashing algorithm: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash",
    "require": {
        "php": "<5.5.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.*"
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've added `"php": "<5.5.*"` to the requirements for the package. You can add this requirement to your own composer.json file, by adding the dependency to your `repositories` array in the composer.json file, and add the requirements there:

```
{
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat",
        "require": {
            "php": "<5.5.*",
        }
    }]
}
```

Something like that, I only have php5.5 installed, so I was unable to test this, though... but read through the documentation, I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: @Ellias Van Ootegem Shouldn't the requirement for this package be: `php: <=5.5`?

Comment: @stixx: You're right, except then that it should be `"php": "<5.5.*"`, as 5.5 is fine